# Can't use null as the first argument for event.dataTransfer.setDragImage in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

http://help.dottoro.com/ljdpgfkx.php

I'm trying to set position of drag image feedback (the image of a dragged element displayed beside the cursor) with

```
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(null, mouseX, mouseY);
```

and I got
**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setDragImage' on 'DataTransfer': setDragImage: Invalid first argument**.

According to http://help.dottoro.com/ljdpgfkx.php. Using null as the first argument should display the default image, but I got the error instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess null won't work. To use the default image use 'this' or whatever your particular reference to the DOM element being dragged is. Here, for example, I ensure it's centered on the mouse:

```
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this, this.offsetWidth/2, this.offsetHeight/2);
```

Hope that helps.